# Flash Point without the Deck Gun?

Tags: house-rules, balance, flash-point

I've played a dozen or so games of Flash Point so far and always find it necessary to have someone be the Driver/Operator, stay in the firetruck, and just use the Deck Gun all game. The right roll can put out five fires at once, the Driver/Operator can use the gun twice per turn, and there's the option to re-roll both attempts at no cost. In other words, it seems like the Driver/Operator is overpowering but essential to the game.

What changes can I make to the rules or to my general strategy if I want to remove the Driver/Operator and still keep the building from collapsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head, but if the issue you're having is that someone needs to be 'stuck' there, then how about giving everyone a special action to skip their whole turn to "radio the driver" to take the action.  This way, effectively, any player can be it without having to be in the truck, and people can take turns.   Try it out, and if it makes the game easier use the game's built in difficulty modification to re-adjust it harder.

Comment: Tried this once where any player could spend 2 AP to drive the firetruck (same as the ambulance) or 2 AP to fire the deck gun (without the ability to reroll). This seems a lot better, but I'll have to give it a few more tries to gauge how much this alters the game difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a major flaw in the base game. To counteract this (a little), my wife and I sometimes use 2 characters each, which is allowed in the official rules. That isn't a complete solution to your problem, though. You might have to part with the base game (and some of your money) to get rid of the problem completely.

I suggest adding the Dangerous Waters expansion to your game. Neither of the two Dangerous Waters maps use the fire truck at all and they are very exciting. I know the subway station in the Honor and Duty expansion doesn't use the fire truck either.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the fact the Driver/Operator can use the gun twice and reroll both attempts is a bit overpowered. A very simple solution would be to discard the reroll modifier, resulting in the special ability of the Driver/Operator to use the water gun at half the cost.

If it's still too easy, change the rules so the Driver/Operator only has a bonus towards driving the vehicle, but using the gun still uses up a total of 4 action points.

Comment: My problem isn't that the Driver/Operator is too good, per se, but rather that the fact that he's necessary. Doing away with the Driver/Operator is virtually a guaranteed loss.